# Matching fixed-format numbers and optional string in regex

Tags: php, regex

Regex newbie! I would like to validate a time string in the format HH:MM with an **optional** space and AM or PM suffix.

Example: **10:30** or **10:30 AM** will both be valid.

Here's what I have so far which is failing:

```
  $test = '12:34';
  if(!preg_match("/^\d{2}:\d{2}?\s(AM|PM)$/", $test))
  {
      echo "bad format!";
  }
```

In addition, is it possible to validate that the HH or MM values are <= 12 and <=60 respectively within the same regex?

Regards, Ben.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\s?[AP]M)?$/
```

Here the last part `(?:\s?[AP]M)?` is an optional, [non-capturing group](http://php.net/regexp.reference.subpatterns) that may start with an optional whitespace character and is then followed by either `AM` or `PM`.

For the number ranges replace the first `\d{2}` by `(?:0\d|1[012])` and the second by `(?:[0-5]\d|60)`.

Comment: @Ben: You’re welcome! By the way, minutes would only go from 0–59 as 60 already is the next hour. And as for the hours, 12=0 in the next 12-hour period.

Comment: Can I trouble you for a little more info? Im trying to support 24 hour time format so the first two digits i.e. can be <=24, however I do not understand the syntax fully - `(?:0\d|1[012])`.

Can you advise on how this breaks down?

Many thanks, Ben.

Comment: @Ben: `(?:0\d|1[012])` is a non-capturing group `(?:…)` containing an alternation of either a `0` followed by a digit, or a `1` followed by one of `0`, `1`, and `2`. So for 24 hours period you would use `(?:[01]\d|2[0-4])` (or `2[0-3]` for `20` to `23`).

Comment: Got it! Thank you, the explanation has been very helpful indeed.

Regards, Ben.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to using regular expression for matching valid minute and hour you can capture them and then use comparison operators as:

```
$test = '12:14';
if( preg_match("/^(\d{2}):(\d{2})(?:\s?AM|PM)?$/", $test,$m) &&
    $m[1] >= 0 && $m[1] < 12 &&  
    $m[2] >= 0 && $m[2] < 60) {
        echo "good format";
} else {
        echo "bad format!";
}
```